# Header row with pandas XLS

Tags: python, pandas

I'm verry new in Python, I try to skip 3 first row in my XLS and defined header from row 3 it's possible ?

df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Feuil1", usecols = 'A:J', header=[3])#, headers=True)

this is my file :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `skiprows=3`, or try using `skiprows=2` and `header=3`.

Comment: so easy ! thanks for support !

Comment: Hello Again, I have one issue in my output, the header is row 4 (undefined )  I don't understand

df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Feuil1", usecols = 'A:J',skiprow =2, header=3)#, headers=True)

Comment: maybe it is because of 1st row is `header=0` 2nd is `header=1` and so on, try using `header=2`